# Import iso into VMWare

Tags: iso-image

I have a Windows 7 software, existing in the iso format. Now I want to extract it to run as a host OS using VMWare.

How to extract iso so that it can run as a virtual machine?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to extract the ISO.  You simply set the CD-Rom device in the virtual machine to load an image.  Then point that image to the location of your Windows 7 ISO.  When the virtual machine is powered on, it will load the Windows 7 ISO as if it were a CD.  You should then be able to install Windows 7 normally.

Comment: File -> New -> Virtual Machine -> Typical -> Installer disc image file (iso)